# Passing function response (callback) as variable to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

See below. I'm trying to pass `function(response)` as a variable to be used in a progress bar function. That's the idea anyways. How do I call back the `data = response` to the `var i = data` in this case?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    var data = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#divToRefresh').load('usercounter.php', function (response) {
            data = response;
        });
    }, 100);
    window.onload = function () {
        var Animator = new function () {
                var parent = document.getElementById('container');
                var element = document.getElementById('test');
                var target = document.getElementById('message');
                this.move = function () {
                    var i = data;
                    var width = 0;
                    var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                        i += 1;
                        element.style.width = width + i + 'px';
                    }, 10);
                };
            };
        Animator.move();
    };
});
```

Comment: How bout just add `$('#divToRefresh').load(... {data = response;});` as the first line of `this.move = function() {`

Comment: and make `var data` a variable local to that move function

Comment: Can you be more precise? I tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. It wont even pass the alert for data. Unless I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your animator works or how those elements interact, but I'm guessing your goal is to call move periodically to refresh it's current status?  So put that in the interval, and then make the retrieval of the count part of the animation.  Not sure if that'll work for your scenario.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });  

    window.onload = function () {
        var Animator = new function () {
                var parent = document.getElementById('container');
                var element = document.getElementById('test');
                var target = document.getElementById('message');
                this.move = function () {
                    $('#divToRefresh').load('usercounter.php', function (response) {
                        var i = response;                      
                        var width = 0;
                        var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                          i += 1;
                          element.style.width = width + i + 'px';
                        }, 10);
                    });

                };
            };
        Animator.move();
        setInterval(function () {
           Animator.move();
        }, 100);
    };
});
```